# How to remember a color of single ListView item when new activity is created

Tags: android, listview, listitem

This is my method to change a color of a single `ListView` item. But I want to remember the color of the last selected item and, if the `Activity` is created (in `onCreate()` method), show it.

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


        l.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        if (save != -1 && save != position){
            l.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        save = position;                
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_go_to_alarams);


            preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.example.projektzaliczeniowy", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            int save = preferences.getInt("positionNr", -1);

            if (save != -1){
                lv.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN); // **HERE IS AN ERROR** 

            }
    }
```

This is fragment of my xml:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.39"
        android:clickable="true" >
</ListView>
```

Sorry for my English :) Can you help me?

Comment: You want to remember the selected item after you close and reopen the application?

Comment: You can store the color or the position of the selected item in the SharedPreferences

Comment: Yes. I want to know how I can reopen this item in onCreate to show for example the color of this item.

Comment: @nem I know that, but just position is not enough. Its because i must have access to ListView to color the selected item.

Comment: I am still unclear on what you want to do here. When you save the color, how and where do you want to use? Is it just to restore when the user comes back to the activity with the list?

Comment: Or are you doing something else with this color?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, i want to restore that when the user comes back to the activity :) The color is just an example because then i want to send PendingIntent too but for now this is not so important.

Comment: Still i have problem with this. I get a Null Pointer Exception in this line: lv.getChildAt(savePosition -1).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

Answer (score 1):

Change the code of your if to this:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(),MODE_PRIVATE);
    int save = prefs.getInt("selected", -1);
    if (save != -1 && save != position){
        l.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    prefs.edit().putInt("selected",position).apply();
```

And on your onCreate

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(getPackageName(),MODE_PRIVATE);
int save = prefs.getInt("selected", -1);
if(save!=-1)
    listview.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: And there is a problem. I have problem with listview in onCreate method. This is how i initialize listview:
'ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);'
But it doesn't work.

Comment: @rewarien What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens when you try this?

Comment: @rewarien maybe it is because you are trying to access the android library id's and not the id's you created. Try changing your statement to one without 'android' ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

Comment: My english here is a problem :P The activity is stopped when i try to run this application. A think it because ListView initialized. Maybe i do something wrong with this. I will edit my post and paste onCreate code.

Comment: @nem i think you are close. I have simmiliar code that Pedro Oliveira fragment above and i whink it should works but something with ListView is wrong. A need findViewById (android.R.id.list)  ( my xml is in Edited post) but  i don't know if i initialize it properlu

Answer (score 1):

You can store the color and the position of the selected item in the `SharedPreferences`

**EDIT**: Since the `SharedPreference` is already given as an answer by @Pedro Oliveira, I will give you some other options.

Global variables for the class:

```
int position;
int color;
ListView lView;
```

You can store the position in a `Bundle` i.e. `savedInstanceState`:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
    // killed or reset.
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Position", position);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Color", color);
}
```

And then in your `onCreate()`:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // here you can initialize your ListView    
    lView = (ListView) findViewById(YOUR_ID);

    // get the position and color from the instance
    // state we saved in onSaveInstanceState
    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
        color = savedInstanceState.getInt("Color");
    }

    // Create OnListItemClickListener and color the item at position

}
```

The Bundle will get passed to `onRestoreInstanceState()` so you can use that as well:

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
    position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
    color = savedInstanceState.getInt("Color");
}
```

To remember a list item, you can also give each list item an id:

- dynamically by calling the `setId(__ID__)` method
- statically in your XML file where the `ListView` is defined by adding `id="__ID__"` property

Then you can store this Id String either in `SharedPreferences` or in a `Bundle savedInstanceState` and use this Id to get the item in your `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use shared preferences

To store the int color value

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("preferences_app", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("color", Color.GREEN);
        editor.commit();
```

//To retrieve and use the int color value

```
SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("preferences_app", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    Integer color = pref.getInt("color", null);
    if(color != null) yourView.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: It's helpfull, thanks. I didn't know that shared preferences can stored color. But it's not exacly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to save temporary state of an activity is to override `onSaveInstanceState()`. This method receives a `Bundle` parameter. You can add data to this `Bundle` which will later be passed to your `onCreate()` method when the activity restarts.

Note that this process only occurs when the activity is destroyed and restarted. If the user returns to the activity by clicking the back button, the activity may not have been destroyed. However, this isn't a problem because all of the activity's settings have been preserved in memory and will be used when the activity is displayed again.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but this problem also happened to me.
I wanted to highlight the item selected and remember that selection even if the app was closed and started again.

Here my solution.
*All the code below was implemented on the onCreate

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, users){
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent); //store the view on a variable, so you can use it later
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this); //initialize sharedPreferences
            int id = sharedPreferences.getInt("CURRENT_ID", -1); 
            if (position == id) {
                int colorId = sharedPreferences.getInt("CURRENT_COLOR", -1);
                view.setBackgroundColor(colorId);//Here we can get access to the specific item, and set the color
            } else {view.setBackgroundColor(1);}
            return view;
        }
    };
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In summary, From the onCreate method you do not have access to an specific adapter item, you need to implement the getView and use:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(colorId);
```

Unlike the `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`
you can easily get access via `parent.getChildAt(someIdPosition)`

I hope this can be helpful for someone in the future.